# Exificient exception "schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document xxx.xsd" with import keyword

Tags: android, xsd, grammar, exificient

I'm trying to create grammars using the exificient-grammars library in Android 15 (c is context)

```java
Grammars g = GrammarFactory.newInstance().createGrammars(c.getAssets().open("svg.xsd"));
```

from svg.xsd, which imports two more schemas: xlink.xsd and namespace.xsd. Those two files came along svg.xsd (as you can see they lie in the root directory along svg.xsd [here](https://github.com/dumistoklus/svg-xsd-schema)). But instead of creating the grammars I get this exception:

```
com.siemens.ct.exi.exceptions.EXIException: Problem occured while building XML Schema Model (XSModel)!
    . [xs-warning] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'xlink.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    . [xs-warning] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'namespace.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

The two lines of the `svg.xsd` that use import are these:

```html
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="xlink.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="namespace.xsd"/>
```

**What I've tried so far:**

1. I've naively tried to merge the two xsd in the svg.xsd to only understand that I was simply unaware of how xsd files work.
2. Followed the source up to `SchemaInformedGrammars.class` but I don't understand what `systemId` is.
3. (edit) Following the suggestions of the support [here](https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient/issues/1) (second post) I used `com.siemens.ct.exi.grammars.XSDGrammarsBuilder` to create the grammars:

```java
XSDGrammarsBuilder xsd = XSDGrammarsBuilder.newInstance();
xsd.loadGrammars(c.getAssets().open("namespace.xsd"));
xsd.loadGrammars(c.getAssets().open("xlink.xsd"));
xsd.loadGrammars(c.getAssets().open("svg.xsd"));
SchemaInformedGrammars sig = xsd.toGrammars();
exiFactory.setGrammars(sig);
```

Only to get the exact same error...

**My question:**
The problem seems to be that the parser cannot locate the two other files. Is there a way to include those files somehow so the parser can locate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**danielpeintner** from the development team of exificient nudged me to the correct direction (issue [here](https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient/issues/24)).

Instead of using the `createGrammar(InputStream)`, Daniel suggested me that I use `createGrammar(String, XMLEntityResolver)` instead, and also provide my own `XMLEntityResolver` implementation. My implementation is this:

```java
public class XSDResolver implements XMLEntityResolver {

    Context context;

    public XSDResolver(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public XMLInputSource resolveEntity(XMLResourceIdentifier resourceIdentifier) throws XNIException, IOException {
        String literalSystemId = resourceIdentifier.getLiteralSystemId();

        if("xlink.xsd".equals(literalSystemId)){
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("xlink.xsd");
            return new XMLInputSource(null, null, null, is, null);
        } else if("namespace.xsd".equals(literalSystemId)){
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("namespace.xsd");
            return new XMLInputSource(null, null, null, is, null);
        } else if("svg.xsd".equals(literalSystemId)){
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("svg.xsd");
            return new XMLInputSource(null, null, null, is, null);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Calling in `createGrammar(String, XMLEntityResolver)` like this:

```java
exiFactory.setGrammars(GrammarFactory.newInstance().createGrammars("svg.xsd", new XSDResolver(c)));
```